# A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /appname has not been defined

Tags: server, websphere

I get the following error message when I try to open up my application from the web (using 'appname' as my application name, the root name of my application - the error displays my app's actual name):

> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /appname has not been defined.

As far as I can tell, my application was installed correctly and is running on our Websphere server (WAS 8.5).

I'm at a loss for what to pursue in order to resolve this issue - what possible issue could my application be having?

Answer (score 0):

Map your web module to /appname in the administration console, or use whatever context-root is specified for the web module.